# Specifying a parameter (x) to be a multidimensional array that has a certain number of columns?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

```
import numpy as np

def validation(x):
    x = np.asarray(x)
    if len(x) != 16:
        return("Card doesn't have exactly 16 digits. Try again")
    values = []
    rwhat = x[::-1]    # reverse the order of the credit card numbers
    rwhat

    checkDig = rwhat[0] # the leftmost [originally rightmost] digit which is the checkDigit ... I'm just doing this because it's easier for me to work with
    checkDig
    withCheck = [] # to append later when we add all single digits

    everySec = rwhat[1:16:2] # we don't want to double the checkDigit, but we're extracting every second digit starting from the first, leftmost digit [tho we omit this checkDigit
    everySec

    def double(num): # to double the extracted second digit values
        return [j * 2 for j in everySec] 
    xx = double(everySec)
    xx

    def getSingle(y): # to add the sum of the digits of any of the new doubled numbers which happen to be greater than 9
        u = 0
        while y:
            u += y % 10
            y //= 10
        return u
    yy=list(map(getSingle,xx))
    yy
    withCheck.append(checkDig)
    withCheck
    new_vv = withCheck + yy
    new_vv # now we include the omitted checkDigit into this new list which should all be single digits

    sumDig = sum(new_vv)
    sumDig # now have the sum of the the new_vv list.

    def final(f):
        if sumDig % 10 == 0: # if the calculated sum is divisible by 10, then the card is valid.
            return("Valid")
        else:
            return("Invalid")
    go = final(sumDig)
    values.append(go) # basically just appending into values[] for the sake of the validation(x) function, and so we can return something for this function. in this case we'd return values as seen below.
    return values
```

So I've created this program, and I need to figure out how to define that the first (outermost) function's parameter takes card numbers as a multidimensional array that consists of exactly 16 columns, and should ultimately return a list of values stating either "Valid" or "Invalid".

The stuff inside the `def validation(x)` works, I've tested it before actually making the said function, but I just don't know how to specify that this function [aka what this program basically is] takes in a multidimensional array of 16 columns.

I'm pretty sure the lines of code regarding `if len(x) != 16` is part of the problem, but it works if we just wanted to run one card [aka one set of 16 digits]

For example, if I wanted to try `validation(([[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6]])` I'm plagued with the output: `"Card doesn't have exactly 16 digits. Try again"` instead of the program properly running and returning me a list that states Valid or Invalid in respective to each card

Comment: Fix your indentation. This is not valid Python as it stands.

Comment: If you want to use numpy, use numpy. Don't use things like `len`, which gives the row count by the way, not the column count, and list comprehensions.

Comment: Ping me when you've fixed the code formatting  and I'll write you an answer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist fixed the formatting. also added some comments throughout the code to clarify what's going on.

Comment: You need to decide: does your function take a single 16-digit input, or a list of 16-digit inputs?

Comment: @JohnZwinck It's supposed to take a "multidimensional array". Not just a single 16-digit input; that was my mistake of including the line of code containing the if statement regarding len, but I was just using that to play around with a single 16 digit input. Basically, want a multidimensional array with exactly 16 columns and n (or whatever variable) amount of rows, where each row represents a 16 digit input [aka a card]

Comment: You switch from 2D array to list and expect everything to magically work without loops.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the basic issues addressed in @JohnZwinck's answer, there is the fundamental fact that you are not using numpy arrays as numpy arrays.

For the program you are writing, there should not be any explicit looping or comprehensions to compute sums or other quantities. Numpy arrays are excellent tools for vectorizing code and simplifying its appearance.

Here are some changes I would recommend in addition to asserting the size of the array:

- Assert that all of the numbers are in the range 0-9:

  ```
  assert np.all((x >= 0) & (x <= 9))
  ```
- Be careful about whether you are using rows or columns. If you have `n` rows of 16 columns each, `checkDig` should be `x[:, 0]`, which is the first column, not `x[0]`, which is the first row, equivalent to `x[0, :]`.
- No need to reverse the array: `checkDig` is just the last element: `x[:, -1]`; `everySec` becomes `x[:, 1:-1:2]`. There is no need for it to be reversed given how it gets used.
- The function `double` is just a mess:

  1. You declare an unused parameter `num`.
  2. You then operate on `everySec` in the enclosing namespace
  3. You apply a list comprehension to a numpy array, which is slower, harder to understand and won't work correctly for 2D arrays.

  You can replace it with just `xx = everySec * 2`, or even get rid of `xx` and just do `everySec *= 2`.
- `getSingle` is overkill. You are doubling numbers nine and under, so the result can have no more than 2 digits (whose sum can be no more than 9). `yy = (xx // 10) + (xx % 10)` should do just fine. By maintaining numpy arrays instead of lists, you can make all the operations work for 2D arrays instead of having to loop over all the individual elements of a list.
- The remainder of your operations are a bit unclear. You appear to be implementing the [Luhn algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm), but there is no attempt to add in the non-doubled digits. The non-doubled digits `x[:, :-1:2]`.
- Calling builtin `sum` will prevent you from processing multiple inputs without a loop. Use [`np.sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html), with `axis=1` to sum the columns in each row.
- `values.append(go)` is only called once. If you wanted to process multiple numbers, you would have to write some sort of loop. It would be much easier to have `go` be a boolean array instead of a single boolean value.

Combining all these suggestions yields something like:

```
def validation(x):
    x = np.asanyarray(x)
    assert x.ndim == 2, "input must be 2D"
    assert x.shape[1] == 16, "input must have 16 columns"
    assert np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.integer), "input must be integers"
    assert np.all((x >= 0) & (x <= 9))
    checkDig = x[:, -1]
    xx = x[:, 1:-1:2] * 2
    yy = x[:, :-1:2]
    sumDig = np.sum(xx, axis=1) + np.sum(yy, axis=1) + checkDig
    return ['Invalid' if s % 10 else 'Valid' for s in sumDig]
```

The function could be further simplified by making a copy of the input to avoid overwriting things, and operating in-place:

```
def validation(x):
    x = np.array(x, copy=True, subok=True)
    assert x.ndim == 2, "input must be 2D"
    assert x.shape[1] == 16, "input must have 16 columns"
    assert np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.integer), "input must be integers"
    assert np.all((x >= 0) & (x <= 9))
    y = x[1:-1:2]
    x[1:-1:2] = ((2 * y) // 10) + ((2 * y) % 10)
    sumDig = np.sum(x, axis=1)
    return ['Invalid' if s % 10 else 'Valid' for s in sumDig]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inspect the `shape`.  Something like this:

```
assert len(x.shape) == 2, "input must be 2D"
assert x.shape[1] == 16, "input must have 16 columns"
assert np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.integer), "input must be integers"
```

Comment: Can you explain that first line and what you mean by "input must be 20" ?

Comment: "Two Dee" not "Twenty."  The first line checks that the input has two dimensions, not e.g. 1D or 3D etc.

Comment: Oh sorry lol. And yeah that makes sense.  So I added that into my code, got rid of the len stuff I originally had, but when I run the program now with the test I had last mentioned in my original post, I'm getting `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'`

Comment: @zainy: Then you have removed the `x = np.asarray(x)` which you had before.  You need to do that first, otherwise you have a list-of-lists, which is not an array.

Comment: I just added that line back in, now when I run the program I get `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158739/discussion-between-zainy-and-john-zwinck).

Comment: `len(x.shape)` is `x.ndim` BTW